# Get DLL or EXE dependencies, using NDepend

Tags: c#, dependencies, ndepend

I need to get the list of referenced assemblies used in EXE or DLL file.
I was looking NDepend as an option to do it through its console so I can have a programatically solution for this.

As far as I know, NDepend reads dependencies from a Visual Studio project, but I don't know if it's possible to tell NDepend to analize a DLL and reads its referenced assemblies.

Anyone knows if it's possible to do it with NDepend? If not, there's another tool or mechanism that I can use to achieve this?

Thank you, Let me know if you need any extra detail.

Comment: [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) will do this for you.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use Reflection to do it programmatically for managed references: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx.
- Or use a tool like JetBrain's dotPeek, also for managed references
- Use Dependency Walker for other kinds of references: http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html

Comment: Yes, I already tried to use Reflection but it is not completely working good.

Comment: Actually I can't. I am not allowed to do it.

The process looks for the DLL into the bin folder of the current running application and not in the reference assembly path of the Loaded DLL. It loads fine the .Net referenced assemblies.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not fully understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain some more? Are you differentiating between managed and unmanaged references?

Comment: Yes, this does not have to struggle with unmanaged references.
I have an application where I can load a DLL or EXE file, I need that application gets the referenced assemblies.
I already tried with Reflection, but it doesn't works fine because when it reach to an application reference it tries to load the DLL from the current running application bin folder, instead loading the assembly from the correct assembly path.

Comment: I adjusted my answer. Dependency Walker is always my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need a [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx), a [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) or if you need these assemblies dependencies programatically NDepend can do that for you.

> so I can have a programatically solution for this.

To get assemblies dependencies programatically you need to use NDepend.API. Here is the [NDepend.API getting started](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html) documentation. Once you got a [ICodeBase](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ICodeBase_members.html) object in memory, here is how to get assemblies dependencies through a C# LINQ query for example:

```
from a in codeBase.Application.Assemblies 
where a.AssembliesUsed.Count() >= 0 
orderby a.AssembliesUsed.Count() descending 
select new { 
   a,
   a.AssembliesUsed,
   a.AssembliesUsingMe
}
```

Notice that `a.AssembliesUsed` is an IEnumerable<[IAssembly](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.IAssembly.html)> that contains application and third-party assemblies. To restraint `a.AssembliesUsed` to only application assemblies used you can rewrite it `assembliesUsed = a.AssembliesUsed.Where(a1 => !a1.IsThirdParty)`.

Also, because NDepend API can be harnessed from C# LINQ query compiled and executed on-the-fly, you can run the previous C# LINQ query in the NDepend query editor in Visual Studio, and get the assemblies dependencies formatted in a convenient way:

[image: Assemblies dependencies with NDepend]